# How can I get the width or height of the dock in Mac OS X so I can resize a window properly?

Tags: applescript

I want to write a code to resize a window by setting its bounds, and I need to consider where the dock is positioned and the size of the dock. I can get the dock's position and its size, but the problem is the size I'm getting is not in an immediately usable form. For example, when I do:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell dock preferences
        properties
    end tell
end tell
```

I get

```
{show indicators:true, minimize into application:false, autohide:false, magnification size:1.0, class:dock preferences object, dock size:0.428571432829, autohide menu bar:false, double click behavior:zoom, magnification:false, show recents:true, minimize effect:genie, screen edge:left, animate:true}
```

How do I translate the dock size of 0.428571432829 into, for example, 100 so that I can set a window (in a 1024x768 resolution) to position `x=100, y=0, h=768, w=924`?

Notice `x` started after the dock, and the `w` is minus the dock width.

Comment: Maybe I’m remembering wrongly, but I thought if you resized a window, AppleScript would take into account the dock and menu bar without the need to do any arithmetic.  Certainly, if I set a window’s position and height to `{0, 0}` and `768` respectively, then—given a menu bar located at the top edge of the screen, with a height of 23px—the window would find itself positioned at `{0, 23}` and its height would be `745`.

Comment: No that's not the case. I learned about it after running the same script on another laptop with a dock positioned at the left (instead of the usual at the bottom). What happens is the window is positioned all the way to the left, behind the dock. I use bounds property only to move and resize the window as the frame and position are marked as deprecated.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about things being marked as deprecated in AppleScript—it means very little, generally, although `bounds` would be the better one to use as `frame` was not universally implemented in the first place rather than deprecation being the issue. But `bounds` is only applicable to scriptable applications. For non-scriptable apps (i.e. most) you'll need to manipulate the `window` by way of System Events, and that will be using the `size` and `position` properties common to all subclasses of `UI element` class objects. Shame the dock is such a pain.

Comment: Oh, and since you'll be accessing System Events anyway, you might like to know the screen dimensions can be obtained like this: `tell app id "com.apple.systemevents" to tell process "Finder" to set [screenW, screenH] to the size of scroll area 1`, which in your case will return `[1024, 768]`. That way, if you change resolution at any point, your script won't need rewriting.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, @CJK. I do believe what you say about deprecation in AS. I did write a small library to help me position windows, and I learned how differently we should position Terminal, Console, and god knows what the 3rd app is (all Apple first-party).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will return the *size* of the **Dock**:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell application process "Dock" to ¬
        set dockSize to ¬
            the size of list 1

return dockSize
```

If you want the *width* and *height*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell application process "Dock" to ¬
        set {dockWidth, dockHeight} to ¬
            the size of list 1


return {dockWidth, dockHeight}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I tried to figure out how you came up with your answer, and I found out that you can get the list by getting the entire contents of the application process dock, then getting its properties contained the attributes I need.